# While ajax, async:true,deferred

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-deferred

3 hours i cant resolve the problem and found solution in internet. Some one please help me.
How i can create loop of ajax requests, while the data from ajax not equally "stop" using while and async:true?

This is not work example:

```
do {
  promise = json('json.php');
  promise.success(function again(data) {
    if(data === 'stop') {
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log('data');
    }  
  });
} while (again()); 


function json(url) {  
   return $.ajax({  
     type: "GET",  
     dataType: 'text',  
     url: url
   });
}
```

Comment: I can't understand your question.

Comment: Your `while` loop is backwards, it would seem. It never loops because you either return `false` or `undefined`

Comment: Be cause my .php return dynamic data.

Comment: You need to make `again()` return true after the `console.log('data')`

Comment: Also, you need to define `again()` as a regular function. Use your error console.

Comment: Another problem, as well, is that you don't call `again` with any arguments in `while(again())`, so it will always return undefined and not loop.

Comment: I added an answer... please learn JavaScript better.

Comment: Ofc it is not work, it is just logic example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function again(data) {
    if (data !== 'stop') {
        alert(data);
        sendReq();
    }  
}

function sendReq() {
    json(location.href).success(again);
}


function json(url) {  
    return $.ajax({  
        type: 'GET',  
        dataType: 'text',  
        url: url
    });
}

sendReq();
```

Comment: How i can use it in while?

Comment: @Jek-fdrv that _is_ a `while`. The `while` keyword is only usable for synchronous loops, which you don't want.

Comment: Well, then it is the best solution for my script. Thank you very much!